# Not able to switch on th wifi in my ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP laptop. I am unable to switch on my wifi. As I switch the toggle key to On position it switches automatically to off position as seen below.

[image: Wireless Off]

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does your laptop have a physical WiFi switch or button on it?  Most do, is it turned on?